# Is it possible to insert a Dell Inspiron 1545 HDD into a normal Desktop PC?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, dell-inspiron

The dell inspiron 1545 had a feature that allowed a user to insert the hard drive like a USB stick of sorts. Plug - & - Play style. Turn off, plug, in turn on, boot drive, finished. But sadly my laptop broke early 2012 and had many important family photos. But now I realized it was a screen problem. Not a disk problem. So I took the disk out. I will not be replacing the screen. Now I am wondering if I can insert it into different computer (Not Dell inspiron) but a Dell Vostro 220. It doesn't seem to fit at all, as it is **VERY** small. Here is a picture of the drive:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qL5uRwA.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a standard 2.5" SATA drive, so yes, it can be connected to a desktop computer. Since you're just getting stuff off it instead of trying to use it for a long time, just connect it to the two necessary cables (power and data), then lay it on the bottom of your PC case or any other good spot for it to rest in a relatively stable position, then turn on the PC. Do this while the PC is powered off and the power plug is disconnected.

You MAY have to go into your BIOS to select the desktop's original HDD as the primary boot drive after this operation, as it may mistake the new drive's boot sector as the desired OS. This will in all likelihood result in a (temporarily) broken boot cycle, so if that happens, you'll know you need to go into BIOS and select another drive to be the first boot choice.

ALTERNATIVELY, put it back into the broken laptop, attach your desktop's monitor to the video out on the side of the laptop, and power the laptop on. You should be able to see everything on the desktop monitor.

Comment: Thx! I will try this now!

Comment: Would this [work](https://www.amazon.com/Blue-7pin-Serial-Power-Cable/dp/B00NM881CQ/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1468023297&sr=1-2&keywords=2.5+sata+data+cord)? Here is a picture of the ports: http://i.imgur.com/LCKXF9P.jpg

Comment: yeah you want to connect the two L-shaped ports and nothing else is needed.